# Differential equation $p=\tan (x-{p\over {1+p^2}})$.

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

This exercise in (non linear ODE. of first order and higher degree - solve in x)

$p=\tan (x-{p\over {1+p^2}})$

My try:

$x=\tan^{-1}(p)+{p\over {1+p^2}}$

Derivative for $y$:

${dx\over dy}=({1\over {1+p^2}}+{{1-p^2}\over {(1+p^2)^2}}) {dp\over dy}$

$p={dy\over dx}$

So

${dx\over dy}={1\over p}$

Then

${1\over p}={{1-p^2}\over {(1+p^2)^2}} {dp\over dy}$

$dy={{p-p^3}\over {1+p^2}} dp$

$\int dy=\int {p\over {1+p^2}} dp -\int {{p^3}\over {1+p^2}}$

$y={1\over 2} \ln (1+p^2)-{1\over 2}p^2+{1\over 2}\ln (1+p^2)$

$y={1\over 2}p^2+\ln(1+p^2)$

so the general solution is

$x=\tan^{-1}(p)+{p\over {1+p^2}}$

$y={1\over 2}p^2+\ln(1+p^2)$

True ?

Thanks.

Comment: Your $\frac{dx}{dy}$ is wrong.

Comment: @xpaul I edited my answer, is it true?

Comment: You ended up with a statement of $y$ as a function of $p$... don't you want the answer to be $y$ as a function of $x$?

Comment: Ok what about now ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure your dx/dy is still wrong.

Comment: @WillieWong what's the wrong, ${dy/over dx} tan^{-1}p$ or ${dy/over dx}{p\over {1+p^2}}$ ?

Comment: It is still wrong.

Comment: @xpaul what's the wrong, ${dy/over dx} tan^{-1}p$ or ${dy/over dx}{p\over {1+p^2}}$ ?

Comment: you took the derivative of $p / (1+p^2)$ wrong.

Comment: @WillieWong what about now? Thanks.

Comment: Okay, you fixed the derivative. But now the line after the word "Then" is wrong. (This will also be my last comment in this thread. Don't you have a Tutor at your local institution that can go over this line-by-line with you?)

Comment: $dy={2\over {(1+p^2)}} dp$ , true ?